# Things you cannot do in London

Tags: london

I am attending some public meeting at London.

May i know what topic i cannot bring up or what kinda stuff i cannot do specifically at London? . I am not sure about their culture.

I am an Asian by the way. Should i tell them that i'm just somewhere from universe?

Below some example someone got beaten.

[Man got beaten when he said We're Chinese](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rfVlZrHx1c)

[Uncle Roger got beaten in London](https://www.thestar.com.my/lifestyle/entertainment/2020/11/01/malaysian-comedian-uncle-roger-says-he-was-a-victim-of-racial-attack-in-london) and He suspects is anti Asian.

Comment: Which area(s) of London will you be visiting/staying in? What type of public meeting are you attending? London is perhaps not as safe as it once was, but in general racist attacks are still rare and providing you follow the usual personal safety precautions applicable to visitors in any large city you shouldn’t have any problems.

Comment: @Traveller Victoria Street. Just online Public speaking and learning class. I need to give a speech like 5-7 . Not physically visit.

Comment: That first link doesn't look much like London.

Comment: You said in comments you are not actually going this meeting in person. Are you going to be in London physically but attending an online meeting? Or are you in some other country and attending an online meeting that happens to be based in London? In either it's pretty unlikely that anyone in London will beat you up following a virtual meeting. Are you just asking how not to offend British people in an online meeting? If so please edit out the bit about "attending a public meeting in London". It doesn't matter where you are if you are online.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about travel but about an online course.

Comment: Try the book “Watching the English” by Kate Fox.

Comment: guys, thanks for info. because my skin color (yellow) , many of us made trouble around world as tourist so i gotta be caution. they hv no chance to study (uneducated) after opium war for 100 years. @Traveller  i.e. in china, kids are allow poo anywhere in the public, i guess london disallow. in china, public toilet are really limited, it was a time i really wanna pee at public dark area. i was seeking for toilet for almost an hour. most mall closed around mid night. i managed to make it at 24 hours MCdonald after 5km walk/ 1 hour walk

Comment: @DJClayworth FYI

Comment: they're really poor during opium war, my nanny was starve to death. guess no chance to study at school to learn about anything about civilization or better manners like British.

Answer (score 6):

London is as safe as any other large cities.

Yes, there is and will be racist (and other non racist) attacks on people that looks different, but they are still rare.

---

"Just online Public speaking and learning class. I need to give a speech like 5-7 . Not physically visit"

According to your latest comment, you have near zero probability of getting physically beaten as you will do virtual meetings

The worse that could happen is cyberbullying, if that happens, the moderator or the virtual room should be able to disconnect the offending party and report to whoever manage those meetings for appropriate punishments.

Comment: I m asking this question because dont wanna to accidentally offended them

Comment: What did you have in mind? As a very general rule, I try to stay away from politics and religion if I'm speaking to a group of people whose backgrounds I don't know.

Comment: @BenBolker you should add your comment as an answer, I think you give good advice. 
I forgot about that, I concentrated of the physical part)  I'll vote for your answer.

Comment: @Ben Bolker I’d add *education* and *sex/gender issues* to that list. Good advice from my grandad :-)

Comment: @littlestar You seem like a person who is very worried about offending people. I would say if you don't say anything mean, and someone is offended, it is their problem, not yours.